# Apache + Mongrel Cluster = Wrong server config!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type, apache2.2, mongrel-cluster

I'm trying to get Ruby on Rails going on a Windows 2003 Server.  I've installed the Mongrel service and Apache (and RoR, etc).

When I serve an app using just Mongrel, everything comes up perfectly.

So, now I am down to the Apache configuration...  Apparently I can't seem to get that right.  When I visit my pages, I am returned the correct HTML, but it's returned with the Content-Type set to text/plain instead of html or xhtml...  In addition, If I try to get to one of the css pages, I get a 500 Internal Server error (served back as HTML, returned with the text/plain Content-Type).

Here is my Virtual Host file (Any help would be VERY VERY VERY appreciated!):

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080


#Proxy balancer section (create one for each ruby app cluster)
<Proxy balancer://myapp_cluster>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  BalancerMember http://rails.localdomain.com:3010
  #BalancerMember http://myapp:3011
</Proxy>




#Virtual host section (create one for each ruby app you need to publish)
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName rails.localdomain.com
  DocumentRoot c:/www/app/public/

  <Directory c:/www/app/public/ >
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
  </Directory>

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPass / balancer://myapp_cluster
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myapp_cluster
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  #SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
  #SetOutputFilter proxy-html

  #log files
  ErrorLog c:/www/log/app_error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog c:/www/log/app_access.log combined

  #Rewrite stuff
   RewriteEngine On

  # Check for maintenance file and redirect all requests
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /system/maintenance.html [L]

  # Rewrite index to check for static
  RewriteRule ^/$ /index.html [QSA] 

  # Rewrite to check for Rails cached page
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]

  # Redirect all non-static requests to cluster
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://myapp_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]


    # Deflate
  #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css
  #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  #BrowserMatch \\bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Oh, and I can change "DefaultType text/plain" to "DefaultType text/html" in the httpd.conf file, and get my HTML pages to show up right, but everything else is still borked..... (plus I don't think that's the right route to take).

Comment: (And when I say "everything else", I mean such things as my CSS and JS pages, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's *part* of the answer.  This part deals with the .css and .js files.  Apparently it relates to trailing slashes...  I had to *remove* some slashes and *add* some others...

Removed:

```
  DocumentRoot c:/www/app/public

  <Directory c:/www/app/public >
```

Added:

```
  ProxyPass / balancer://myapp_cluster/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myapp_cluster/
```

Now I can pull up the .css and .js files just fine...

HOWEVER:  I am still having the issue of Apache NOT sending the right headers.  Right inside the HTML that I'm returning I have this:

But it's STILL returning text/plain (the DefaultType as set in the httpd.conf).

PLEASE, if anyone has any ideas, let me know!!!!!

Thanks

Comment: I think, it is mongrel_cluster who doesn't set content-type header.

Comment: Check if http://rails.localdomain.com:3010 returns a correct content-type. If it returns nothing, then apache applies the default one.

Answer (score 0):

I heavily recommend a linux host for RoR. Unicorn and Passenger are way better tools than mongrel clusters. See [github blog post about it.](http://github.com/blog/517-unicorn)